# TCL proc for default value assignment

Tags: tcl

What is the syntax for a proc in tcl which automatically takes arguments if user din't give any arg?

I used something like

```
    proc a {{args 1}} {
    puts $args
    }

    a
```

when I used this I dint get my args value as 1. It returns a blank string. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to do two different things together:

1. Accept a variable number of arguments to your proc
2. If no arguments are provided, use default value(s)

There isn't really a syntax for proc that handles this case specifically. However, it's fairly easy to accomplish. You can accept a variable number of arguments (`args` keyword), and then check to see if any were supplied (and use a default value if not).

```
proc myproc {args} {
    if { [llength [info level 0]] < 2 } { #called with no args
        set args {the default list of values}
    }
    # rest of the code goes here
}
```

The `info level 0` command returns the actual command being run as it was called, with arguments. Hence, if the length of it's result is < 2, we know the current command was called with no arguments (since the first element in the list is the actual command name itself).

Answer (score 1):

The word `args` is a reserved word that has a specific meaning in proc definitions. Use a different variable name:

```
proc a {{x 1}} {
    puts $x
}

a
```

---

### Additional answer

In a proc definition, default values are given by defining the argument as a list with two members: the first will be the name of the argument, the second is the default value.

The word `args` is a special argument that implements rest arguments (that is, it captures remaining arguments not specified in the argument list). This is how one can implement variadic functions in Tcl.

The `args` arguments and default values can be used together when defining procs. But `args` cannot have default values. Any argument listed before `args` can have default values. But arguments that have default values must be listed after arguments without default values. So, basically you can write a function like this:

```
proc a {x {y 1} args} {
    puts "$x $y ($args)"
}
a 1       ;# prints 1 1 ()
a 1 2     ;# prints 1 2 ()
a 1 2 3 4 ;# prints 1 2 (3 4)
```

If your use-case meets this pattern then you can define arguments with default values before `args` like the example above. If not, then your only option is to process `args` yourself:

```
# Assume parameters are key-value pairs,
# if value not given then default to 1
proc b args {
    foreach {x y} $args {
        if {$y == ""} { set y 1 }
        puts "$x -> $y"
    }
}
b 1 2    ;# prints 1 -> 2
b 1 2 3  ;# prints 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks! but if I am right, "args" alone can take list of values to the proc. My input to this proc is from another proc and it can feed any number of args. How to deal with this?

Comment: for example

        **a 1 2 3 4 5**
this works only if args are used.

Comment: The current procedure implementation assigns actual parameters to formal arguments in a strictly left-to-right fashion. This means that there's no reason to put a default value on a formal parameter before another formal without; that will just be ignored (and cause probably-confusing error messages). Also, `args` is only special when it is the last formal argument; anywhere else and it is just a normal formal.